# Validate variable is in range Java

Tags: java

I have three integers, which are assigned to variables after being passed in as command line parameters. I want to validate that each of the integers are in the range 1-5. Is there a way to accomplish this in Java without using an if statement like the one below? I'd like to avoid doing this (note- pseudocode):

```
if ((a & b & c) > 0 && (a & b & c) < 6) {
//blah blah
}
```

Mainly, this wouldn't scale well if additional parameters were added in the future, etc. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: Wait.If you had only 1 variable, how would you expect to find if it is in range *without* using an `if` so that you are asking if this could be expanded to `N` variables?

Comment: All three variables must be in the same range, (1-5)

Comment: You're going to have to use an if statement, but there better ways to do it as a lot of the answers below show.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only improvement I think could be made (for readability) is this:

```
public boolean isInRange(int i) {
    return i > 0 && i < 6;
}
```

Then call that function instead.

If `a`, `b`, and `c` are related, you may also consider using an array and looping through that. Something like:

```
public boolean allInRange(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        if (!isInRange(arr[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this:

```
validate(int ... args) {
    for (int arg : args) {
        if (arg < 1 || arg > 5) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Argument is not in valid range [1..5]: " + arg);
        }
    }
}
```

and then call this helper method

```
validate(a,b,c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method to which you pass an integer, and the method can return a `boolean` depending whether or not it is in range.

Another way is to create a method that receives a list of integers `List<Integer> myList` or an array of integers, and checks each and every one if it is in range.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a faster way to do that without using multiple `&&`s (**for integers only**):

```
private static boolean isInRange(int num, int min, int max) {
    return (num - min - Integer.MIN_VALUE) <= (max - (1 - Integer.MIN_VALUE));
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isInRange(5,1,7)); // true
    System.out.println(isInRange(5,1,3)); // false
}
```

Comment: why not `num > min && num <= max`? That's a **LOT** more readable.

Comment: I believe it is a little bit faster (Note that there is no `&&`)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Even if it were faster, your compiler/jitter is smart enough to optimize it properly.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I always use `num > min && num > max`.. I just wanted to show another way to do that.. But.. talking about this.. say we you need to check the range for 1000 numbers.. does it make a difference then? (I just gave this solution to show another way of doing that.. I know it's much less readable)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't know. Profile it.